# Function called only once from another script

Tags: unity, c#

I have a spawn function which is

```
public void spawnobstacle(){
    number_of_spawn = Random.Range (1, 3);
        if (number_of_spawn > 0) {
            spawnposition = Random.Range (0, 3);
            if (spawnposition == 0 && !rightisoccupied) {
                Instantiate (obstacle, rightpos, Quaternion.identity);
                rightisoccupied = true;
            }
            if (spawnposition == 1 && !midisoccupied) {
                Instantiate (obstacle, midpos, Quaternion.identity);
                midisoccupied = true;
            }
                if (spawnposition == 2 && !leftisoccupied) {
                Instantiate (obstacle, leftpos, Quaternion.identity);
                leftisoccupied = true;
            }
            number_of_spawn -= 1;
    }
```

and I have another script in the obstacle GameObject that if the obstacle is triggered by it, it destroys the obstacle and spawn some other obstacle.

The content of the script is this:

```
public class DestroyObstacle : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject world;
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D thecollision){
    if (thecollision.gameObject.tag == "destroypoint1") {

        world.GetComponent<Spawn> ().spawnobstacle ();
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
}
void Start(){
    world = GameObject.Find ("World");
    }
void Update() {

}
```

Why is the function only calls one obstacle every time and the function is called only once, 2 times max (not every time the obstacle is destroyed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to clear the `rightisoccupied` `midisoccupied` and `leftisoccupied` flags when an obstacle is destroyed.

One option would be to add a variable to the spawned obstacles which state the lane they are on. Have the `DestroyObstacle` check that variable and clear the corresponding flag in `Spawn`  before calling `.spawnobstacle ()`.

Another option would be to replace these flags with a reference to the actual game object. When you destroy a game object, it will be equal to `null`. So when you `Destroy` the rightObstacle and then call `.spawnobstacle()`, `rightObstacle == null` will be true.

Comment: I love you, you glorious person.